# React-native link does not relink after manually removing the links

Tags: xcode, react-native, npm, react-native-linking, ios-library

The `react-native link` command works normally the first time I install an `npm` dependency.

During debugging I manually removed contents of the Libraries and Frameworks folders in my iOS project and since then the `react-native link` command is unable to link them again.

My Libraries and Framework folders are empty:

[image: Libraries and frameworks not linked]

My `Project Settings > Target > Build Phases` are also empty only with some imports from Pods. Specifically `Link Binary With Libraries` and `Embed Frameworks` phases.

However, the `react-native link` command returns success:

```
$ react-native link
warn The following packages use deprecated "rnpm" config that will stop working from next release:
  - rn-fetch-blob: https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob#readme
Please notify their maintainers about it. You can find more details at https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/configuration.md#migration-guide.
info Linking assets to ios project
info Linking assets to android project
success Assets have been successfully linked to your project
```

Seems like a caching problem, but not sure where to clean its cache.

Comment: Which React Native version are you using?

Comment: @PetrBela 0.61.5

Comment: Yeah similar to the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60530791/react-native-unable-to-import-react-headers-after-updating-to-0-60), in RN 0.60+, linking doesn't update xcodeproj anymore, instead it adds to the Podfile (and, as many libraries use auto-linking now, `react-native link` is not needed anymore).