# React Native: Unable to import React headers after updating to 0.60

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-linking, ios-library

After updating to React Native `0.60` the header linking does no longer work.

I'm having problems linking from the `React library` during build:

```
/Users/User/Developer/Project/node_modules/react-native-image-resizer/ios/RCTImageResizer/RCTImageResizer.m:12:9: fatal error: 'React/RCTImageLoader.h' file not found
#import <React/RCTImageLoader.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

What changed in `0.60`:

- The file `RCTImageLoader.h` is now at `/node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules`.
- The file `React.xcodeproj` that contained these headers is no longer present

[image: React Native folder]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were [many changes in React Native 0.60](https://reactnative.dev/blog/2019/07/03/version-60), one of the main ones is that React modules are now packaged using CocoaPods, which replaces header linking.

I recommend you generate a new project in 0.60+ and check out its project structure (mainly the `Podfile`). You can also use the [upgrade helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/) to see what's changed.

Answer (score 2):

It took me 3 hours. Finally I found the solution:

Use specific version 1.1.0 by running the command:

```
npm install react-native-image-resizer@1.1.0
```

Then run the command:

```
cd ios && pod install
```